# angular regex for a certain pattern

Tags: regex, angular

I am new to angular and I have not worked with regex. I have a requirement. Form bag field type has 3 characters and a `/` and then other 3 characters.

My resolve is

```
let x = new RegExp("^[abc]{3}$-[abc]")
```

This is not working. Please help me.

Comment: Look like you want `let x = /^[a-z]{3}\/[a-z]{3}$/i;`

Comment: https://regexr.com/

Comment: Thanks Wikfor. let str = “abc/abc”. I test this as new RegExp(x).test(str); is it ok to use test function. However I get false

Comment: See my answer with a correct test showing `true` for the `abc/abc` string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put the end of string anchor `$` in the middle of the pattern making it fail for any string as there cannot be a `-` and a `a`, `b` or `c` chars after the string end. Also, `[abc]` only matches `a`, `b` or `c` letters, while you might want to match any ASCII letter. Also, you say you need to match `/` and used `-` in your patter.

Use

```
let x = /^[a-z]{3}\/[a-z]{3}$/i;
```

It will match

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z]{3}` - 3 ASCII letters (thanks to the `i` case insensitive modifier, the `[a-z]` will also match `A-Z` range)
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `[a-z]{3}` - 3 ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

JS test:

```js
let str = "abc/abc";
let x = /^[a-z]{3}\/[a-z]{3}$/i;
console.log(x.test(str));   // ==> true
```